# Force table column to not excess given css width

Tags: html, css

HTML

```
<table >
<tr>
    <td>veeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeery looong</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
table {
    width: 80px;
}
td {
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 25%;
    width: 25%;
}
```

I want every column to be 25% of 80px, thus 20px in size. How do I stop the first column from getting larger (its content can be hidden).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use `table-layout: fixed`

```
table {
    width: 80px;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    table-layout: fixed;
}

td {
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 25%;
    width: 25%;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

An example: http://jsfiddle.net/wsastn47/1/

**edit:**  @mevius suggestion word-wrap: break-word;

Comment: Add a `word-wrap: break-word;` to the `td`, and you have yourself a good solution.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest the following:

```
table {
    width: 80px;
}
td {
    width: 25%;
    border: 1px dotted blue;
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

Use the `word-break` property to allow the long text strings to wrap within the table
cell and remain visible.

See demo: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/7ptrtwac/

Note: The `max-width` property is not needed for `td`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following CSS as well :

```
table {
width: 180px;
border-collapse:collapse; 
table-layout:fixed;
}
td {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 25%;
  width: 25%;
  word-wrap:break-word;
  border:solid 1px;
```

}

Demo link [DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Pvr73/10/)